# CephFS needed if you only need block storage?

Tags: proxmox, ceph

I'm looking into building a CEPH cluster as a storage solution for our proxmox cluster.

It's unclear to me if I need to set up a metadata server too, because this is needed for CephFS but I think CephFS is not used for RBD, correct?

Comment: There are lots of openly available docs that coming the information you're looking for. There's a lot of additional information you'll find helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `mds` is only needed for `cephfs`. For `rbd` you only need `mons`, `osds` and `mgrs.`